# Trace of a Summation of Positive Definite Matrices with a Real Coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-definite, matrix-analysis

> Show that $$\mbox{tr} \left( \sum_{i=1}^k (\alpha A_{i} + B_{i})^2 \right) \geqslant 0, \qquad \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$$ given that $A_{i}$ and $B_{i}$ are positive definite $n \times n$ complex matrices $\forall i=1,\dots,k$.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $(\alpha A_i + B_i)^2$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Still can't figure out why.

Comment: The square of a Hermitian matrix is positive semidefinite.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Why does the question require A and B to be positive definite? Isn't being symmetric sufficient?

Comment: Hermitian, not symmetric (**complex** symmetric matrices are not Hermitian) is sufficient.  Note that any matrix can be written as $-A + B$ with $A$ and $B$ positive definite..