# Trace of a Summation of Positive Definite Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, matrix-analysis

Given that $$tr \Bigl( \sum_{i=1}^k (\alpha A_{i} + B_{i})^2 \Bigr) \geqslant 0 \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R} $$
with $A_{i}$ and $B_{i}$ being positive definite $n\times n$ complex matrices $\forall i=1,...k$

How can I deduce that $\bigg( tr \Bigl( \sum_{i=1}^k A_{i}B_{i}\Bigr) \bigg)^2$ $\leqslant$ $tr \Bigl( \sum_{i=1}^k A_{i}^2 \Bigr)tr \Bigl( \sum_{i=1}^k B_{i}^2 \Bigr)$

I tried substituting -1 instead of $\alpha$ and expanding yet I'm stuck.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3496193/339790

Answer (score 2):

Replace $\alpha$ by $-\alpha$ in your first expression. After expanding it, you get
$$
\def\tr{\text{tr}}
-\alpha\sum \tr A_i^2-\frac1\alpha\sum\tr B_i^2+2\sum\tr (A_iB_i)\leq 0,\\
\sum\tr (A_iB_i)\leq\frac12\left( \alpha\sum \tr A_i^2+\frac1\alpha\sum\tr B_i^2\right)
$$
for $\alpha>0$. Then choose $\alpha$ in such a way that $\alpha\sum \tr A_i^2=\frac1\alpha\sum\tr B_i^2$. Apply the inequality $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\ge ab$ where $a= \alpha\sum \tr A_i^2$ to get the result.

---

Alternatively, you can just prove that it is an inner product space. Let $X$ be the set of $k$-tuples of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices. Let $\mathbf A=(A_1,\ldots,A_k)$, and similar for $\mathbf B$. $\mathbf A,\mathbf B\in X$. We consider the function
$$
\langle \mathbf A,\mathbf B\rangle:=\tr\left(\sum_{i=1}^k A_iB_i\right).
$$
We can verify that $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product. This makes $X$ an inner product space. Then apply the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) which is true for all inner product spaces.

Of course, $X$ has other different inner products, since $X\subseteq\mathbb R^{kn^2}$. The inner product I described above, however, is one of a few inner products that are "bilinear" for matrices, i.e. for all matrices $M$,
$$
\langle M\mathbf A,\mathbf B\rangle=\tr M \cdot\langle \mathbf A,\mathbf  B\rangle, \langle \mathbf A,M\mathbf B\rangle=\tr M \cdot\langle \mathbf A,\mathbf  B\rangle
$$